# Relation between identity transformation and transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hamel-basis

Suppose $T: V \to V$ is the identity transformation.

If $B$ is a basis of V, then the matrix representation of $[T]^B_B = [I_n]$.

Let's say C is also a basis of V, then it is clear that $[T]^B_C \ne [I_n]$.

However, I was taught that matrices representing the same linear transformation in different bases are similar, and the only matrix similar to $I_n$ is $I_n$. Thus, $[T]^B_C$ and $[T]^B_B$ are not similar.

Can anyone clear what seems to be a contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the statement “matrices representing the same linear transformation in different bases are similar” means is that if $B$ and $C$ are bases, then $[T]_B^B$ and $[T]_C^C$ are similar.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: @AshuvHalim What do you mean? Do you want a proof of the fact that $[T]_B^B$ and $[T]_C^C$ are similar? You'll find it in any Linear Algebra textbook.